# Perl: Isolate character in line using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Sorry to ask such a simple question but **I really suck at regular expressions** and I've been searching online for about 45 minutes now.

This is the string: "R 3"

R can be R, G, B, or Y. 
I want to isolate whatever that letter is to put in the variable $color.
I've tried doing this:

```
$color = "R 3";
$color =~ s/![rgby]/[rgby]/g;
```

And this:

```
$color = "R 3";
$color =~ s/[rgby]/g;
```

Can someone please throw me a bone and tell me what the combination would be? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You want to substitute to remove anything that *isn't* R, G, B, or Y:

```
$color = "R 3";
$color =~ s/[^RGBY]//g;
```

(use `/gi` instead of `/g` if you want either upper or lower case colors)

or instead of substituting, you can use the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr):

```
$color =~ tr/RGBY//cd;
```

or you can just extract the single character that you want, and leave the original string unchanged:

```
$string = "R 3";
($color) = $string =~ /([RGBY])/;
```

Comment: I think he wants to grab the R, G, B, or Y.

Comment: @squiguy: s/he has the input in $color and says the output should be in $color too.

Comment: @ysth: Yeah it doesn't seem likely to be the real requirement but I think you've covered every possibility.